# xcode archive "Library not found for -lReact-hermes" for ReactNative project

Tags: xcode, react-native, xcodebuild, react-native-hermes

Trying to archive my RN project but having this error. Currently using RN 0.65.1 with React 17.0.2.
Tried adding `libReact-hermes.a` inside xcode "Link Binary With Libraries" but error still persists.

```
ld: library not found for -lReact-hermes
```

---

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'MyAppp' do

  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => true
  )

  use_flipper!()
end
```

Comment: Any idea? same error...

Answer (score 2):

There is an option in Xcode to change the deployment target.

Make sure that that is also marked as `11.0`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

change

```
IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.0
```

to

```
IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 11.0
```

in .pbxproj file

same idea as @Amaan posted, but it didn't change all the targets until edited all the values in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my **Podfile** content as below:

```
platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
:hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
```

to

```
platform :ios, '12.4'
:hermes_enabled => true,
```